# Cycle plugin: cycling through divs, "too few slides"?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle

I'm using Cycle to attempt to cycle through some divs that are generated by another jQuery function.  Here's the function:

```
$.getJSON('../functions.php', function(images) {
  $.each(images, function() {
    $('#slideshow').append('<div class="slide" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');
  });
});
```

I'm having a weird issue.  The DIVs are appearing, and if I use the Chrome Inspector I can see them, but they don't show up if I view the source explicitly.  Maybe that doesn't matter, but when I run:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle();
```

I get an error in the console that says:

> [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 0

You can see the site live here: http://new.element17.com

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is that you're populating your slideshow images using `getJSON` method.

Even though this method is located before you cycle method, `getJSON` is asynchronious method that's why cycle is running before loading images.

Solutions:
1. Use `.ajax` instead of `.getJSON` with `async: false`

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: '../functions.php',
    success: function() {
        $.each(images, function() {
            $('#slideshow').append('<div class="slide" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');
        });
    }
});
```

2 Move `$('#slideshow').cycle();` inside `.getJSON` method so it run after loading images.

```
$.getJSON('../functions.php', function(images) {
    $.each(images, function() {
            $('#slideshow').append('<div class="slide" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');
        });
        $('#slideshow').cycle();
    });
```

**This code is not tested**

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206871/cycle-plugin-cycling-through-divs-too-few-slides#answer-13206971),  You are making an async request with
    $.getJSON

So when cycle is being called, no data has yet returned from the request meaning no html has been appended inside 'div#slideshow' so as expected

> [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 0

**To Fix this:** run cycle after the async request is finished.  I wouldn't recommend doing a synchronous call

```
$.getJSON('../functions.php', function(images) {
    $.each(images, function() {
        $('#slideshow').append('<div class="slide" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');
    });

    $('#slideshow').cycle();

});
```